# Should I set div demensions using EM's?

Tags: css

I am going to be giving users the option of changing the size of the text via some controls on the page. What I would like to know is if the user changes the size too much, will the text start to wrap around in the div's incorrectly and should I be using EM's to specify my div width / height to avoid this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you link to the other question? Also, could you potentially clarify the first paragraph? It's kind of a [run-on sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence) and consequently is difficult to understand.

Comment: Made the changes as suggested; not sure how to clarify the question so have left it and am hoping it is clearer with my edits.

Comment: I have reworded the question completly now as I think this is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on what you'd like to accomplish.  Usually, the text won't wrap incorrectly, unless you are giving it a font size so big that a word won't fit on one line, in which case that word won't wrap at all.  If you are merely allowing the user to have font size of, say, 12px, 16px, and 20px, then you can just keep the div the same width if you want to keep the viewing area at a comfortable width for the user.

You can also consider setting some reasonable width of the page to match certain font size, so that the page width doesn't directly scale by `em`, but to some reasonable width, because monitors have a few preset width such as 1024, 1280, 1600, and 1920 and making the width wider probably isn't convenient for the users.

Comment: I think that answers my question good enough, thanks. I have been playing around and have used EM for the divs and everything is scaling really well at the moment so I will see how it goes. I am trying to avoid being limited to a set range of font sizes so this is working the way I wanted it to.